# How to access an object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have the data like below when i log it in browser console.

```
const items = getItems(); //this has the logged value
{data: {..}}

data:
    outer:
        first: []
        second: Arrary[2]
            0: {id: '1', name: 'name1'}
            1: {id: '2', name: 'name2'}
```

I want the second array of objects so the output should be

```
second: Array[2]
    0: {id: '1', name: 'name1'}
    1: {id: '2', name: 'name2'}
```

i have tried below,

```
const output = data.outer.second
```

but says cannot find data.

could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Comment: Looks like `data` is a property within another object. What exactly are you _logging_ when you _"log **it** in browser console"_

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What object you use inside `console.log()`?. Suppose you are using object `items` as `console.log(items)` then you need to get `second` array like below.

```
let second = items.data.outer.second;
```

You can test it below.

```js
const items = {
  data: {
    outer: {
      first: [],
      second: [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'name1'
      }, {
        id: '2',
        name: 'name2'
      }]
    }
  }
}

let second = items.data.outer.second;
console.log(second);
```